# Why isn't the 'mask' class working in my Bootstrap 5 project?

Tags: javascript, html, background-image, mask

The latest Bootstrap 5 is giving a tough time in adding `class="mask"` to my background image. It doesn't even work at all.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-image">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489987707025-afc232f7ea0f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80" class="w-100" />
    <div class="mask " style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) ;">
      <div class=" justify-content-center align-items-center b-100 ">
        <hi class="text-white">
          product details
        </hi>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where do you see `mask` in the Bootstrap documentation? Also, I don't recommend using a beta version.

Answer (score 3):

Mask is a part of Material Design for Bootstrap ([mdbootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/content-styles/masks/)), you need to include it.

```
<link
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/4.2.0/mdb.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/4.2.0/mdb.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489987707025-afc232f7ea0f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80" class="w-100" />
        <div class="mask" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) ;">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
                <h1 class="text-white">
                    product details
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/docs-app/css/dist/mdb5/standard/core.min.css">
<div class="bg-image">
  <img
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489987707025-afc232f7ea0f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80"
    class="w-100"
    alt="Louvre Museum"
  />
  <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <p class="text-white mb-0">product details</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fixed the Bootstrap link, and added useful classes to rightly position the text div on the image.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain _what this code does_. Read [answer]: how does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: There's no mention of MD Bootstrap in the question.